# Will the existing wiring work with the new thermostat?

Tags: electrical, thermostat

I am looking to upgrade my line voltage thermostat from a Dimplex mechanical thermostat to a Honeywell digital thermostat. Both thermostat has 2 wires on its back. Would the new thermostat work if I connect it the exact same way that I connected the old thermostat?

The current dimplex thermostate https://www.dimplex.com/en/electric_heating/thermostats_controls/products/ts_td/line_voltage_thermostats

Here's the one I want to upgrade to
https://www.honeywellstore.com/store/products/non-programmable-thermostat-line-volt-baseboard-rlv3150a1004.htm#

I couldn't find a manual for the rlv3150, but there is one for rlv3120 https://www.honeywellstore.com/store/images/pdf/RLV3120-Owners-Manual.pdf

My gang box has 6 wires (not counting the bare copper wires). 2 wires each coming from 3 holes -- two holes near the top and 1 hole near the bottom.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Other notes

- Thermostat controls electric baseboard heaters, no fan
- 240V - my electric panel has 2 linked switches for the baseboard heaters
- Each baseboard heater uses 1500W or less
- All the red wires from the gang box are connected together
- The two black wires that are connected together are from the top two holes
- The existing thermostat does not seem to be connected to the ground? The tiny copper wire on the bottom screw is cut off and not connected to anything.

Comment: The holes are less relevant than the **cables** which group multiple wires.